# Creating a list of data frames (or some other structure) from a messy .csv file

Tags: r, csv

**tl; dr -- I believe this is actually a simple problem, just requires an elaborate explanation to set up the context. Pass over a file once and build a list of data.frames**

I have a messy `.csv` file shown below. It contains a lot of "junk" lines -- lines containing data that are of little use/interest or lines with embedded spaces, tab characters, etc. The lines that are valuable include:

(a) DETAIL
(b) Sub-Detail
(c) The "data-frame-like" object following the DETAIL and Sub-Detail line.

However, the number of junk lines between (a), (b), and (c) can vary such as in the example (`testing.csv`). What I would like to return is a list of `data.frame` objects such as `results` or something very similar (for example, I have considered a result where the `Detail` and `SubDetail` are captured as additional columns in the `data.frame`):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Item = 1:3, Val1 = c(50, 20, 30), Val2 = c(100, 30, 50))
df2 <- data.frame(Item = 1:2, Val1 = c(20, 30), Val2 = c(30, 50))
df3 <- data.frame(Item = 1:2, Val1 = c(10, 30), Val2 = c(20, 40))
df4 <- data.frame(Item = 1:3, Val1 = c(50, 30, 70), Val2 = c(30, 40, 80))

# One possible desired result structure
results <- list(list(Detail = "01", SubDetail = "ABC", data = df1),
                list(Detail = "01", SubDetail = "XYZ", data = df2),
                list(Detail = "02", SubDetail = "ABC", data = df3),
                list(Detail = "02", SubDetail = "XYZ", data = df4))

str(results)
```

The sample `.csv` file (`testing.csv`) looks similar to this snippet:

```js
xxx
  
xx
DETAIL: Detail 01
Sub-Detail: ABC
x
xxxx
x
Item, Val1, Val2
1, 50, 100
2, 20, 30
3, 30, 50
x
xx
xxx
x
  
    
DETAIL: Detail 01
Sub-Detail: XYZ
x
Item, Val1, Val2
1, 20, 30
2, 30, 50
x
x
DETAIL: Detail 02
Sub-Detail: ABC
Item, Val1, Val2
1, 10, 20
2, 30, 40
xxx
xx
x
x

DETAIL: Detail 02
Sub-Detail: XYZ
Item, Val1, Val2
1, 50, 30
2, 30, 40
3, 70, 80
x
xx
```

---

Let's assume I already have a way of identifying the "bad lines" in the file. This means, I can effectively print the lines like so:

```
badLine <- function(line) grepl(pattern = "^$|^\\s|^\\t|^x", line)

con <- file("testing.csv", open = "r")

while (length(oneLine <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
  if (badLine(oneLine)) next else print(oneLine)
} 

close(con)
```

Which yields:

```
# [1] "DETAIL: Detail 01"
# [1] "Sub-Detail: ABC"
# [1] "Item, Val1, Val2"
# [1] "1, 50, 100"
# [1] "2, 20, 30"
# [1] "3, 30, 50"
# [1] "DETAIL: Detail 01"
# [1] "Sub-Detail: XYZ"
# [1] "Item, Val1, Val2"
# [1] "1, 20, 30"
# [1] "2, 30, 50"
# [1] "DETAIL: Detail 02"
# [1] "Sub-Detail: ABC"
# [1] "Item, Val1, Val2"
# [1] "1, 10, 20"
# [1] "2, 30, 40"
# [1] "DETAIL: Detail 02"
# [1] "Sub-Detail: XYZ"
# [1] "Item, Val1, Val2"
# [1] "1, 50, 30"
# [1] "2, 30, 40"
# [1] "3, 70, 80"
```

**How can I build the `results` object (or a similar object) without passing over the file again?**

It's safe to assume that the following helper functions could be leveraged to identify their respective lines:

```
detailLine <- function(line) grepl(pattern = "^DETAIL: ", line)
subDetailLine <- function(line) grepl(pattern = "^Sub-Detail: ", line)
dfHeaderLine <- function(line) grepl(pattern = "^Item", line)
dfLine <- function(line) grepl(pattern = "^[[:digit:]]", line)
```

Comment: Is there a memory problem with reading in the file and applying the filters after? `alltext <- readLines("testing.csv"); filteredtext <- alltext[!badLine(alltext)]`?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Probably not, so that could be an option. Still leaves a wrinkle in splitting up the `data.frames` of varying length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be best to first read in the data then apply the filters instead of applying them as you read in line by line.

```
#Read in data
alltext <- readLines("testing.csv")

#Apply filter to isolate headers and lines
onedf <- read.csv(text=alltext[dfHeaderLine(alltext) | dfLine(alltext)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)

#Split by header
alldfs <- split(onedf, cumsum(dfHeaderLine(onedf[,1])))

#Correct column names
alldfs <- lapply(alldfs, function(x) {names(x) <- unlist(x[1,]);x[-1,]})

#Make Detail and Subheader lists
dtl <- as.list(alltext[detailLine(alltext)])
sub <- as.list(alltext[subDetailLine(alltext)])

#Combine all lists
results <- Map(list, dtl, sub, alldfs)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "DETAIL: Detail 01"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "Sub-Detail: ABC"
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# Item  Val1  Val2
# 2    1    50   100
# 3    2    20    30
# 4    3    30    50
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "DETAIL: Detail 01"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "Sub-Detail: XYZ"
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# Item  Val1  Val2
# 6    1    20    30
# 7    2    30    50
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the [suggestion of @PierreLafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256888/creating-a-list-of-data-frames-or-some-other-structure-from-a-messy-csv-file#comment62041301_37256888) in the comments and using the `data.table` package:

```
alltext <- readLines('testing.txt')

badLine <- function(line) grepl(pattern = "^$|^\\s|^\\t|^x", line)

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(txt = alltext[!badLine(alltext)])

DT[, grp := cumsum(grepl('DETAIL', txt))
   ][, `:=` (detail = gsub('DETAIL: Detail ','', grep('DETAIL', txt, value = TRUE)),
             subdetail = gsub('Sub-Detail: ','', grep('Sub-Detail', txt, value = TRUE))),
     by = grp
     ][, .SD[4:.N], by = grp
       ][, c('Item','Val1','Val2') := tstrsplit(txt, ',', type.convert = TRUE)
         ][, c('grp','txt') := NULL][]
```

which results in the following datatable:

```
    detail subdetail Item Val1 Val2
 1:     01       ABC    1   50  100
 2:     01       ABC    2   20   30
 3:     01       ABC    3   30   50
 4:     01       XYZ    1   20   30
 5:     01       XYZ    2   30   50
 6:     02       ABC    1   10   20
 7:     02       ABC    2   30   40
 8:     02       XYZ    1   50   30
 9:     02       XYZ    2   30   40
10:     02       XYZ    3   70   80
```

*Explanation*:

- After removing the *bad lines* with your `badLine` function, you convert it to a 1 column datatable `data.table(txt = alltext[!badLine(alltext)])`.
- With `[, grp := cumsum(grepl('DETAIL', txt))]` you create a grouping variable that separates the different dataparts. `grepl('DETAIL', txt)` creates a logical value detecting the lines that start with `DETAIL` (and indicate the start of a new datapart). Using `cumsum` on that creates an grouping variable.
- With `detail = gsub('DETAIL: Detail ','', grep('DETAIL', txt, value = TRUE))` you extract the detail-number (as well as for `subdetail`).
- With `[, .SD[4:.N], by = grp]` you remove the first three lines per group (because they do not contain data and the needed info is already extracted in the previous steps).
- With `[, c('Item','Val1','Val2') := tstrsplit(txt, ',', type.convert = TRUE)]` you convert the data which is still in text format in the `txt` column into three data columns. The `type.convert = TRUE` makes sure that the data gets the right format (numeric in this case).
- Finally, you remove the `grp` and `txt` columns with `[, c('grp','txt') := NULL]` (because they are not needed anymore).

To see what each step does, you can also use the following code:

```
DT[, grp := cumsum(grepl('DETAIL', txt))][]
DT[, `:=` (detail = gsub('DETAIL: Detail ','', grep('DETAIL', txt, value = TRUE)),
             subdetail = gsub('Sub-Detail: ','', grep('Sub-Detail', txt, value = TRUE))),
     by = grp][]
DT[, .SD[4:.N], by = grp][]
DT[, c('Item','Val1','Val2') := tstrsplit(txt, ',', type.convert = TRUE)][]
DT[, c('grp','txt') := NULL][]
```

Adding `[]` to each line, makes sure that the result gets printed to the console.

Comment: Thank you - I think I follow, but would you mind chopping this up into a few a steps and providing some context/comments?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I will add an explanation tomorrow (hopefully in the morning)

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I've added an explanation, HTH. Let me know if you need more info.